# Separate rate limit for nginx GET and POST

Tags: nginx

I want to apply different value of rate limit for GET and POST in nginx.

Below code doesn't seem to give desired result

```
     map $request_method $req_post_limit_per_ip {
      default    "";
      POST       $remote_addr;
    }


    map $request_method $req_get_limit_per_ip {
      default    "";
      GET       $remote_addr;
    }

    limit_req_zone $req_post_limit_per_ip zone=post_limit_per_ip:10m rate=100r/s;
    limit_req_zone $req_get_limit_per_ip zone=get_limit_per_ip:10m rate=1000r/s;
```